# How is the dependent clause acting in this sentence?

Tags: clauses

Today I came across this sentence,

“Happiness is when I play games after a tough day at work.”

In this sentence, I wasn’t sure how “when I play games,” a dependent clause, is acting. It’s a complement to “is,” but is the clause a predicate nominative? Also, is it an adverb or noun clause?

Comment: In order to understand the sentence structure, you do not need the prepositional (adverbial) phrases or an object. You can simplify the sentence: *Happiness is when I play."* This should be understood as *"[For me,] happiness exists/occurs/is felt when I play"* -- *When I play* is a subordinate adverbial clause.

Comment: I would call it a nominal relative clause. It's a subject complement and functions as predicate noun. https://www.thoughtco.com/free-nominal-relative-clause-1690808

Comment: It's a _Wh_-complement clause (aka 'embedded question' and 'headless relative'), like _I don't know what he sees in her_. [Complement clauses (there are four types, of which this is one)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) are noun clauses, usually subjects or objects, though this one is essentially the predicate nominal (with its obligatory _be_ auxiliary) in the sentence, while _Happiness_ is the subject. To the extent you can reverse the NPs, you can also parse it as an equational sentence.

Comment: You're on the right lines. "When I play games after a tough day at work" serves as the **predicative complement** of "be" in its specifying sense. The analysis of the _when_ expression is in fact quite problematic. One solution is to treat it as a Prep phrase, with "when" as head and a subordinate content clause as complement. Alternatively, "when" could be classified as a subordinator, thus the expression is a subordinate clause. I would avoid the term 'noun clause' -- it's a misnomer. Noun is a part of speech, not a clause type.

Comment: @BillJ I’m a bit confused why noun clauses are misnomers. Isn’t it taught that the types of clauses are relative, noun, and adverbial? If you don’t call them noun clauses, what would you call them, or is it situational? Also, is saying a clause is adverbial, and relative fine, just not saying “noun” clause? 
Thanks, I appreciate it. A

Comment: Also, you said “when” can be a preposition to start a prepositional phrase? I’ve never known this: Is this applicable to situations similar to this with “when?” Thanks again

Comment: The clauses that trad grammar wrongly calls 'noun clauses' are actually ‘content’ clauses, which generally function as complements -- nothing at all to do with nouns.  It’s important to distinguish syntactic category and function. By category, clauses are divided into main or subordinate, and then into finite (relative, comparative and content) and non-finite (gerund-participial, past participial, infinitival). Content clauses are the default kind of finite subordinate clause.

Comment: Functionally, content clauses are generally complements, though some grammars also call subjects complements. In your example, if "when" is taken to be a subordinator, then _when I play games after a tough day at work_ is a content clause. For those who take “when” to be a prep, it is a prep phrase.  In both cases its function is complement of “be”. As I said previously, the treatment of “when” as a prep is controversial, and best kept for grammarians and linguists.

Comment: @BillJ I really appreciate the in depth response. I was taught that “clauses” that are non finite are not really clauses, but they are actually phrases. For example, saying “Preparing some breakfast, the man took out the milk.” In phrases like this, or any “non finite clause,” why is it a clause if it doesn’t have a subject? Please correct me if I said something wrong or gave a bad example.

Comment: I found an example of one “I’m going to broadway to watch a play” from Wikipedia. Why isn’t this just an infinitive phrase? Once again, I was taught the phrases are participle, gerund, and infinitive, as well as prepositional. Like “I don’t like going to the theater.” Isn’t this just a gerund phrase, why a clause? (If it is a non finite clause)

Comment: They are clauses because they have a subject-predicate structure, even though the subject is not overt but understood from the context as some person or thing. In your first example, the subject of "preparing" is _understood_ as "the man", and in the second and third examples the subject of "going" is _understood_ as "I". It's a more accurate grammar than the one in trad grammar, which unfortunately is still in circulation.